# How to use dynamic column name in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I want use dynamic column names in my query, so I use `execute format`. But my query does not work. This is my query...

```
create or replace function container_type() returns table (contType text) as 
$func$ 
declare 
    containerType text[] := '{d20, r20, h20, rh20, e20, d40, r40, h40, rhc, e40, 45, tank, tk40, tk45, e45, r45, rh45, h45}';
    column01 text;
    column02 text;
begin
    FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper(containerType, 1)
    loop
    column01 = upper(containerType[i]);
    column02 = concat('"booking_', containerType[i], '"');

    execute
    format(
        'insert into tmp_booking_containers (
            booking_data_source,
            booking_place_of_creation,
            booking_prefix,
            booking_number,
            booking_prefix_number,
            booking_container_type,
            booking_container_quantity
        ) select 
            booking_data_source,
            booking_place_of_creation,
            booking_prefix,
            booking_number,
            booking_prefix_number,
            $1,
            $2
        from dim_booking_masters 
        where $2 != 0'
    ) using column01, column02;

    end loop;
end
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

This is the error shown when I run my function:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up `format` and the `USING` clause of `EXECUTE`.

`format` replaces occurrences of `%I`, `%L` and `%s` (danger! no escaping!) in its first argument with the following arguments (cast to `text`).

You use it if you need to interpolate things like table and column names.

The `USING` clause of `EXECUTE` is to specify arguments for parameters, like in prepared statements. The arguments are bound to the `$1`, `$2` (and so on) placeholders. You can only use parameters where you could also use a constant of some type in SQL.

Both techniques protect you against SQL injection.

Your code should look like this:

```
EXECUTE format(
            'insert into tmp_booking_containers (
                booking_data_source,
                booking_place_of_creation,
                booking_prefix,
                booking_number,
                booking_prefix_number,
                booking_container_type,
                booking_container_quantity
            ) select 
                booking_data_source,
                booking_place_of_creation,
                booking_prefix,
                booking_number,
                booking_prefix_number,
                %I,
                %I
            from dim_booking_masters 
            where %I != 0',
            column01, column2, column02;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I have fix my query. But I got new error like this..."SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions
  Where: PL/pgSQL function container_type() line 15 at EXECUTE". I think the error come because I use loop. Thanks

Comment: No, that error means that you have something like `INSERT INTO tab (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 2)`. Seems like an unrelated problem.